# not enough arguments for format string with bool and list

Tags: python, mysql

I'm newbie to python and trying to update one column value (true/false) of all rows (ids provide in list) using `IN` on list.

My query is like this :

```
qry = "Update table Set "\
      "col1 = %s "\
      "where col2 in ( " + ",".join( "%s" for _ in lstIds)
qry += ")"
cursor.execute(qry,(col1Value, lstIds))
```

But I'm getting error

> not enough arguments for format string

I've tried different solutions but unable to resolve my issue.
When I change my query this way, `it works fine`

```
qry = "Update table Set "\
  "col1 = 1 "\
  "where col2 in ( " + ",".join( "%s" for _ in lstIds)
qry += ")"
cursor.execute(qry,( lstIds))
```

So I guess issue is in first parameter value but I dont know how to resolve this.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Nooo.... Don't format queryes that way.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: they are not interpolating values, only query parameters.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I know, but still it is not an elegant way to do that.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem isn't that a good way to avoid sql injection and all that?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: there is no better way for an `IN` membership query.

Comment: @NullPointer: It has nothing to do with sql injection, more that it is inelegant to write sql queries. Usually it is better to use libraries for that (like SQLAlchemy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include each of the values in `lstIds` as a separate parameter:

```
cursor.execute(qry, (col1Value,) + lstIds)
```

assuming `lstIds` is a tuple, or

```
cursor.execute(qry, [col1Value] + lstIds)
```

if it is a list.

Or you can combine the sequence into one list with the `*` notation in Python 3.5 and newer:

```
cursor.execute(qry, [col1Value, *lstIds])
```